# Where can I find the xmodemsend command in TeraTerm

Tags: command-line, installation

I have installed TeraTerm's latest version on my Windows PC. I was reading the help menu of the TeraTerm and they reference the 'xmodemsend' command to transfer a file over Xmodem protocol via command line. I searched my TeraTerm directory for this command but can't seem to find it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

xmodemsend is a macro command.

http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/macro/command/xmodemsend.html

If you want to send the file interactively with the TeraTerm window, Select:

File->Transfer->XMODEM->Send...